# still get message on server (imapd) Failed IMAP login from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (CID/Country/-) even i already logged out from any software

Tags: server, imap, webmail

i want to ask a question. every day my IP always got blocked on server, and this is the message:

> (imapd) Failed IMAP login from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (CID/Country/-) ........

I already logged out my mail from other software (outlook, tb, mail) and only using browser. Anyone have any suggest for my problem?

Comment: If it’s a publically reachable server, it will be hit by random bots all the time.  Make sure your passwords are strong.

Comment: is that the cause of my IP always blocked every day?

Comment: Is that xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx your IP?

Comment: yes, and that's a dynamic IP. so it changes everyday